# adaptive indentation in emacs?

Tags: emacs, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs code to automatically set indent-tabs-mode according to existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726376/emacs-code-to-automatically-set-indent-tabs-mode-according-to-existing-code)

When I'm editing old files in a group where other people may work on them tomorrow or ten years from now, I like to adopt the file's existing tab or space indentation scheme for my additions/changes - that's just being polite, but it's currently something of a hassle.  Does anyone have a way for emacs to look for the current indentation scheme in the file or at least the neighboring lines and use that for Tab indentation?

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate - thanks for tracking that down.

Comment: Despite the author himself consider it's a duplicate, I think his question doesn't only deal with `indent-tabs-mode` (what about `c-basic-offset`, `tab-width` and/or other indentation configurations ?). This question and phils answer deserve more attention/discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sound promising:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GuessStyle
- https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/dtrt-indent/
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FuzzyFormat

A comparison/review would be interesting.

Comment: Dang, I bow to your superior search-fu!  I missed those completely.

Comment: I was pretty sure I'd seen something relevant in CategoryIndentation at the Wiki, so that made it easy :) I'd forgotten about dtrt-indent, but I'm sure that cropped up elsewhere recently, and I'd meant to look into it more at the time.